# Проверить, существует ли файл

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Имеется путь на локальной машине (UNIX) вида:

```
/system/site/photos/000/342/small/12104_%281%29.jpg?1468158362
```

Пытаюсь проверить, существует ли файл, но все варианты, которые я нашёл в Google или документации, выдают всегда `false`.

```
    small_img = photo.url(:small)
    unless File.file?(:small)
      small_img = photo.url(:original)
    end
    render partial: 'common/image_preview',
           locals: { original: photo.url, thumb: photo.url(:thumb), medium: small_img }
```

Comment: А если сходить руками с помощью `cd` по файловой системе, какой полный путь до этого файла? Он там вообще есть?

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но я боюсь даже представить, как это должно работать: `File.file?(:small)`. А вообще, очень похоже на `Paperclip`. Если угадал, то не надо изобретать велосипед. Надо посмотреть документацию. Всё уже изобретено. И да, сомнительно как-то в качестве пути к файлу использовать `url`. Как минимум, есть методы, позволющие получить именно путь в файловой системе.

Comment: Файл физически есть, если я просто пытаюсь выдать этот урл без проверки - все работает. Но у меня в массиве много объектов, у которых этих изображений вообще нет.

Comment: @anoam О каком велосипеде идет речь? Мне надо просто проверить файл на существование <code>File::file?
File.file?(file_name)   => true or false
Returns true if the named file exists and is a regular file.</code> Если в документации есть что-то на этот счет или я чего-то не того вообще ищу или делаю - можно ссылкой или ключевой фразой?

Comment: @СтаниславИльин, именно об этом. У Paperclip'а есть [родной метод](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#checking-a-file-exists) проверки существования файла. Вот его и надо использовать. При чём, его описание на главной странице репозитория, очень странно, что Вы его не заметили.

Comment: @anoam if photo.url.exists?(:small) undefined methos exists - Такая же ситуация с file?, к сожалению... С этого, я, как раз, начал и не понял, как ими воспользоваться (приложение дописываю, тут и был этот метод, но он не отрабатывал, а на деве - вызывает фатал). Может я что-то при инициализации paperclip упустить мог? ))

Comment: @СтаниславИльин, внимательно читаем документацию. Потом разбираемся какой метод для какого объекта.

Comment: @anoam никакой не является подходящим просто потому что данные методы не доступны в приложении... В документации все красиво, все должно работать - однако, данная тема появилась исключительно потому что ни exists ни file паперклипа не работают в приложении... Но, в любом случае, спасибо за комментарий.

Comment: Пардон, `photo` какого класса? И какого класса результат выполнения `.url`? Урл - строка. Какой смысл спрашивать у строки "ты существуешь?". Что это даст? А вот `photo` - интереснее. Если это Paperclip то `photo` - `Attachment`. И **у него** есть такой метод. И если бы Вы потратили 15 минут чтобы разобраться как это всё работает - стало бы очевидно, что нужно вызвать `photo.exists?(:small)` а не гадать на кофейной гуще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для проверки существования файла предназначены методы класса `File`

```
File.file? '/path/to/file.png'
File.exist? '/path/to/file.png'
```

`file?` проверяет существование файла и что это именно файла, в то время как `exist?` проверяет существование и файла, и директории и ссылки.

Обратите внимание, что в качестве аргумента передается именно путь к файлу в виде строки. В вашем примере передается символ `:small` - это не верно, Ruby-класс `File` ничего не знает о Rails и отношениях в вашем приложении, он ждет путь, ему не достаточно стиля, как в случае метода `url` вашей модели (которая о файле знает все).